# How does this work? (rational numbers)

Tags: java

For example, I have a code in modules and I want do this:

```
sum = r1.add(r2); //I don't understand how does this instruction work :(
```

r1 is a Rational number
r2 is a Rational number

I don't want to know how to make the code or the method, I want to know what does this instruction do.

Thanks.

Comment: since we don't know what datatype it is, how can we know? it migt be anything.

Comment: Is this the source code of the said class ? : http://www.ecs.umass.edu/ece/ece122/lectures/lect16/RationalNumber.java

Comment: The method `add()` is called on `r1` with a parameter `r2` and returns something (probably a sum of `r1` and `r2`). That wasn't so hard, was it?

Comment: What JAVA types are r1 and r2? Also, on most IDE's if you hold the Ctrl key and click on the add method, it will direct you to its implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The question is king of broad but we can infer a few things that can give you the chance to get the answer to your question:

my assumptions are:

- r1 and r2 are objects of the same class (I will named RClass, and just base this because of the name rules that you are using)
- the class r has a method with the signature `add(RClass myObjectR)`
  since the method's name is **add** I thing you are doing math addition so RClass has a field that is numeric.
- the method add is assigning its return value to a variable named sum (summatory maybe?) therefore the method "can" return a numeric value.

based on all this assumptions I will do this:

## R-Class definition:

```
public class RClass {

    private final int x;

    public RClass(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int add(RClass t) {
        return this.x + t.x;
    }
}
```

## And to test this:

```
// test
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final RClass r1 = new RClass(10);
    final RClass r2 = new RClass(17);
    int sum = 0;
    sum = r1.add(r2);

    System.out.println("The result is: " + sum);
}
```